# bind9, Resolve example.com but forward *.example.com to a forwarder possible?

Tags: bind, delegation

is it possible in bind to resolve example.com with a zone but resolve all subdomains of example.com with a forwarder?

If somebody knows how this can work or has some simple sample configurations i would love to hear about it.

Thanks!

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding here. "Rsolve to a zone" and "Delegate subdomains to a forwarder" is the same thing, or at least conflicts.

Comment: You can have a wildcard DNS entry so **anything** that does not explicitly resolve (not actually defined in the zone database) gets forwarded. I am not sure if you can wildcard NS records though. Have you looked at NAPTR records, I am not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: ust tried with MS DNS and it does ***not*** work.

Comment: I realize that normally this would create a loop but in my case the authoritative domain servers are different ones, so resolution for the ones that do not match would still be possible and not result in a loop.